Definition of left/right divisors
I am studying algebra and can't clearly understand definition of divisors. Could you confirm that I understand the following concepts correctly, please?
Let M - set, $a,b,c \in M$, then:
1.1  Element $b$ is a $\textit{right divisor}$ of element $c$, if $\exists a \in M : a \cdot b = c$
1.2  Element $a$ is a $\textit{left divisor}$ of element $c$, if $\exists b \in M : a \cdot b = c$
2.1 A set of all $\textit{right divisors}$ of $c$ is: $R = \left \{ a \cdot b \; | \; b \in M  \right \}$
2.2 A set of all $\textit{left divisors}$ of $c$ is: $L = \left \{ a \cdot b \; | \; a \in M  \right \}$
I'm more interested in 2.1 and 2.2 because as for me it's more clear to write $R = \left \{ b \in M  \; | \; a \cdot b = c \; , \; a \in M  \right \}$.
Thanks for any help.

The first two definitions are fine. Definitions 2.1 and 2.2 do not make sense, as they are written. The way you wrote $R$ is more precise, perhaps you could write $R=\{b\in M\ |\ a\cdot b=c,\text{ for some }a\in M\}$.
